# Resampling scalar field from unstructured mesh to rectlinear grid

Tags: mesh, resampling, paraview

I have an unstructured mesh with a scalar nodal field assigned to it and I need to convert it into a rectilinear (i.e. Cartesian) grid with the field interpolated onto it. I managed to convert the mesh geometry into a binary image using vtk's polydata2maskimage, but am struggling to map the field to this grid.

I have tried Paraview's "Resample to Image" and "Resample With Dataset" filters (including after the conversion of the nodal field into a cell-based one), but could not get them to do what I want.
I have also tried the likes of Matlab's griddata and nearestNeighbor, but that sampled locations that were too remote (effectively creating what looks like a funny convex hull of the object) or required a very specific Matlab delaunay object format to work...

I would be grateful for some help! Thanks,
Marta

Comment: It seems that Paraview's "GaussianResampling" does the trick, although I am still struggling to get my head round its multiple parameters.

Comment: What is the problem with `Resample to Image` ? You can also try `Point Volume Interpolator` (with linear kernel)

Comment: "Resample to Image" just gives me weird-looking points. Also, it creates a ghost field that I cannot remove. When I ask for the data to be saved, it is the ghost field rather than the scalar one I am interested in that gets saved.